# Bitbucket - Tower - Undo/Delete Previous Commits

Tags: git, git-tower

I have been through quite a bit of posts, but I cannot get this to work.  So...  I am using Tower and accessing a remote branch called stag.  I am trying to undo/delete commits that were done after a certain commit (let's say hash - 0008).

A couple of notes: there are others that use this branch (they pushed the wrong commits - so they know this is coming) and I don't care about losing history or anything after 0008.

I've tried a `git reset --hard 0008`, which works locally, but doesn't push to remote without a pull that undoes it.  I can logon to bitbucket directly if need be.

I've tried a `git revert` back 60 commits, but got "Commit #3434353 is a merge but no -m option was given. fatal: revert failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it - noted below for others:

```
git reset --hard 0008
git push -u origin branchName --force
```

If some has a better solution please share and I'll mark it.